# Unable to pass value to NSString inside `Grand Central Dispatch`

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

```
__block NSMutableString *retCode;

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    retCode = @"1";
    self.returnCode = retCode;
});
```

I'm using this code, but it passes a `NULL` value to `returnCode`;

Comment: You can assign the `retCode value` outside the block..

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use NSMutableString in the instance you're giving first of all ( since you're overwriting the value ).  So, you could use `NSString` just as easily (probably better too unless you actually intend to append/prepend/manipulate that string within your dispatch ).

That being said, you should also consider applying a `__weak` reference to self before going into your block.

```
__weak typeof( self ) weakSelf = self;
```

Finally, returnCode may actually be NULL *IF* you are trying to access it on the main thread - which is not on the same thread as your DEFAULT priority global queue.  I make this note because it depends on *when* you are attempting to access your self.returnCode - because if you try to see if it is not nil *before* the block inside of your dispatch queue is executed then yeah - it will be nil/null.

Try `NSLog( @"Value of returnCode = %@", self.returnCode );` and you should see it is actually being assigned.

full example:

```
__block NSString *retCode;
__weak typeof( self ) weakSelf = self;

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    retCode = @"1";
    weakSelf.returnCode = retCode;

    NSLog( @"Value of returnCode = %@", weakSelf.returnCode );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using the `NSMutableString *retCode`, so u need to assign the `@"1"` in `NSMutableString` not a `NSString`

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

  retCode=   [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"1"];
//use here or
self.returnCode = retCode;

});
```

Comment: try this , if u need any assistance I am change my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
 __block NSMutableString *retCode=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];

AppDelegate* __weak weakSelf = self;


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

[retCode appendString:@"1"];
    weakSelf.returnCode = retCode;
    NSLog(@"%@",weakSelf.returnCode);

});
```